# Zonal statistics in R: using exactextractr to extract the counts of a range of pixel values from a raster

Tags: r, zonal-statistics, extract

I have a raster with pixel values from 0 to 20, and I'm trying to count each pixel value with R package exactextractr. I have the raster ('def'), a SpatialPolygons object ('grid10') and an empty dataframe ('results'), pre-filled with NAs, with 21 columns x 10066 rows (there are 10066 polygons for which I want to extract counts). This is what I get:

```
> for (i in 0:20){
+   z <- exact_extract(def, grid10, function(value, count) {
+     count[value == i]
+   })
+   results[,i+1] <- z
+ }
  |==================================================================================================================| 100%

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i + 1, value = list(c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement element 2 has 754 rows, need 10066
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i + 1, value = list(c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  replacement element 1 has 10284 rows to replace 10066 rows
```

Can anyone suggest a correction?...I can't be far away from the correct code, as the following code works to extract the proportion coverage for each pixel value:

```
for (i in 0:20){
  message(i)
  z <- exact_extract(def, grid10, function(value, coverage_fraction) {
    sum(coverage_fraction[value == i],na.rm = T) / sum(coverage_fraction,na.rm = T)
  })
  results[,i+1] <- z
}
```

The code to set up the 'results' df was:

```
lenval <- length(grid10@data$left)
results <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow = length(seq(1:lenval)), 
                             ncol = length(seq(1:21))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through 0:20 you may use `table` function which gives you the count per each different value.

```r
library(exactextractr)
library(raster)
# build a raster layer
rast <- raster::raster(matrix(sample(20, 100, replace = T), ncol=10), xmn=0, ymn=0, xmx=10, ymx=10)

# and a polygon layer
poly <- sf::st_as_sfc('POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))')

exact_extract(rast, poly, function(value, coverage_fraction ) {table(value)})

value [,1]
   1     4
   2     2
   3     1
   4     1
   6     1
   ...
# just to compare vs the whole raster
table(rast[])
 1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
11  4  3  7  7  4  7  4  2  1  7  7  6  3  3  4  5 10  5

# exact_extract considers also pixels that fall partially within the polygon
plot(rast); plot(poly, add = T); text(rast)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - with my 10066 polygons and using function(value, count) I get what looks like a list of 10066 tables - here's an extract: 
[[4]]
< table of extent 0 >
[[5]]
value
  2   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  15  16  20      
  1 314 270 137 139  51   6  28   1   6   7  12 
[[6]]
value
2 
1 
....there are even a few -1 pixels I wasn't expecting! But is it possible to get this into a dataframe where the columns are pixel values (0 to 20) and the rows are the 10066 polygons?

Comment: You can do something like `exact_extract(rast, poly, function(df) df %>% group_by(id, value) %>% summarize(tot = sum(coverage_fraction), .groups = 'drop') %>% pivot_wider(id, names_from = value, values_from = tot), summarize_df = TRUE, include_cols = 'id')` (uses dplyr and tidyr)

Comment: Thanks @dbaston....does this mean that for exactextratr, sum * coverage fraction = count of individual values?!  But it seems to work all the same.

Comment: If you want to disregard the coverage fractions and count touched pixels, do `tot = n()` instead.